# PHP and Apache - how do I stop having so much stuff written to logs

Tags: php, apache

I have a bit of an outdated hosting company. I have a PHP/Apache setup.

For some reason, it keeps writing a lot to the log files.  There are two log files:

access_log and error_log

I never look into the access log, so is there some apache config that can be turned on or off that would stop all writing to the access log?

And for the error_log, I get a lot of things there very randomly.

```
[Sun May 20 00:56:28 2012] [error] [client 92.96.145.124] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  photo_path in /home/webadmin/problemio.com/html/utils/api/somefile.php on line 398
[Sun May 20 00:56:28 2012] [error] [client 92.96.145.124] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  photo_path in /home/webadmin/problemio.com/html/utils/api/somefile.php on line 398
```

But those are notices.  How can I just make it show me warnings and errors?

Thanks!!

Comment: Here's the Apache documentation on log files: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/logs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include one of these two at the top of the page/header and this should take care of the notices (based on what you want to see).

```
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

Comment: thanks! That helps very nicely.  But is there a way to do that in the settings/configurations?

Comment: There should be an error reporting field in your php.ini file, the applicable values are all listed here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Answer (score 1):

I used to face the same problem. I asked the CS about this and they simply answer that "it can't". I ended up with writing a cron script to delete those garbage files.

Comment: that sounds terrible :) Actually I think it takes a lot of resources to write that stuff to the file system so I really need it to not happen at all.

Answer (score 1):

This variable is in use when not defined

> photo_path in /home/webadmin/problemio.com/html/utils/api/somefile.php on line 398

you need to find the file. find error.